# display comboBox value of fom1 to another form in Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

I have three forms Form1, Form2 and Form3. I have a comboBox in form1 which I want it to be displayed in Form 3.
Question: So what I want is that when I select the value of comboBox in form1 and click the button, it should open form2 and in form2 when I click the button again, It should show the comboBox selected value in a textbox in Form3.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //form1
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // don't know what to put in this parameter
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    ComboBox CB1;
    public Form2(ComboBox cb1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CB1= cb1;
        cb1.Text.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(CB1);
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }

public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    ComboBox Combo;
    public Form3(ComboBox combo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Combo = combo;
        Combo.Text = combo.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You asked a similar question yesterday. Anyways send the ComboBox.Selectedvalue as a string. Dont send the combobox object.

Comment: Yes but this gives an error.
//Form2 f2 = new Form2(comboBox1.SelectedValue);

Comment: Is there a ctor in form2 which takes 1 string arg ?

Comment: no form2 doesnt take any string arg

Comment: Refer my answer. Depending on the arg you send, a corresponding ctor should be present in next form to receive it. On form load the ctor will be invoked accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION1:**

One simple solution is defining a static property in your first window for the selected item,

```
    public static string SelectedItem;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And in Window3, you can assign the value like this,

```
    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtresult.Text = MainWindow.SelectedItem;
    }
```

**SOLUTION2:**

```
    If you have to pass the value through the constructor just pass the selectedItem as a String through each window, something like this,

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(combobox.SelectedItem.ToString());
    f2.ShowDialog();
}

string result = null;
public Form2(String selected)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    result = selected;

}
```

In form 3,

```
public Form3(string result)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Combo.Text = result();
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 worked perfectly. Thanks @sajeetharan for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the event from form1 to form2

```
Form2 obj = new Form2(ComboBox1.SelectedValue);
this.Hide();
Form2.Show();
```

In form2:

```
string someName="";
public form2(string name)
{
InitializeComponent();
someName=name;
}
```

Comment: Form2 obj = new Form2(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
This worked. thanks for your help again.

Comment: Yes. Jus remember my point about having as many ctors as needed.